# stormcrawler currently compatible with which version of Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler

What version of Apache Storm should I have installed in order to use the latest version of StormCrawler?

Apache Storm 1.2.3 or 2.0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of writing, the master branch of StormCrawler is based on Storm 1.2.3 as shown in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/pom.xml#L67), but there is a [2.x branch](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/2.x/pom.xml) available as well.

Comment: I've tried to say Thanks a few times here but the interface doesn't seem to let me..or does it...